# Django redirect problems

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and I'm having problems with redirect the user after authorization. Here is 200 code in the console.

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}.")
            return redirect("test")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request=request, template_name="login.html", context={"login_form": form})


[27/Jan/2022 14:41:26] "POST /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[27/Jan/2022 14:41:26] "GET /account/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 136
```

the same with

```
redirect(reverse("test"))
```

Comment: Hi there,

Do you want to pass a hardcoded URL to redirect or the name of the view ?

Can you copy the part of the file `urls.py` where you add the view, please ?

Make sure there is no view `/account/test/` which has a `name="test"`.

Comment: hi! that's name of the view

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', CreateUser.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', user_login, name='login'),
    path('test/', test, name='test'),
]